# Global setting for all image urls in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Is there anyway to set a global image setting, route, or anything so that all images reference a CDN url without having to update every image? So when I use the HTML helper like this:

```
$this->Html->img('some_image.jpg');
```

Instead of referencing `/img/some_image.jpg`, it will point to:

```
http://cdn.example.com/img/some_image.jpg
```

**UPDATE**

Final solution was simple. Thanks @burzum for the push in the proper direction. Here is what I did.

In AppController I added:

```
public $helpers = array(
    'Html' => array(
        'className' => 'MyHtml'
    )
);
```

Then I created the override helper:

```
<?php
// app/View/Helper/MyHtmlHelper.php
App::uses('HtmlHelper', 'View/Helper');
class MyHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {
    // Add your code to override the core HtmlHelper
    public function image($path, $options = array()) {
        $path = 'http://cdn.localhost/'.$path;
        return parent::image($path, $options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply overwrite the image() method in a customized helper extending the HtmlHelper and use the 2.1 aliasing feature for helpers:

```
public $helpers = array(
    'Html' => array(
        'className' => 'MyHtml'
    )
);
```