# how to set the full base url to a cdn while using HtmlHelper in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cdn, cakephp-2.3

My cakephp app is running on 2.4.0

It is already running live on yourapp.com

I am attempting to use Amazon CloudFront to serve static assets like css, js, and images.

The CDN domain I chose was `cdn.yourapp.com`

Sadly, when I tried to use it this way:

```
echo $this->Html->css('alpha_landing/styles', array('fullBase' => $cdnBaseUrl));
```

where `$cdnBaseUrl` is `http://cdn.yourapp.com/`

I did not get back the correct url I was expecting.

I was expecting

```
http://cdn.yourapp.com/css/some.css
```

But I got back

```
http://yourapp.com/css/some.css
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions:

Simply write a HtmlHelper that can override the default image, css, etc functions

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601207/80353 for details

or

you can rewrite the assetUrl function in your AppHelper so that you need not rewrite all the related functions.

```
public function assetUrl($path, $options = array()) {
    $cdnBaseUrl = Configure::read('App.assetsUrl');
    $legitCDN = (strpos($cdnBaseUrl, '://') !== false);
    if (is_array($path)) {
        $path = $this->url($path, !empty($options['fullBase']));
        if ($legitCDN) {
            return rtrim($cdnBaseUrl, '/') . '/' . ltrim($path, '/');
        }
        return $path;
    }
    if (strpos($path, '://') !== false) {
        return $path;
    }
    if (!array_key_exists('plugin', $options) || $options['plugin'] !== false) {
        list($plugin, $path) = $this->_View->pluginSplit($path, false);
    }
    if (!empty($options['pathPrefix']) && $path[0] !== '/') {
        $path = $options['pathPrefix'] . $path;
    }
    if (
        !empty($options['ext']) &&
        strpos($path, '?') === false &&
        substr($path, -strlen($options['ext'])) !== $options['ext']
    ) {
        $path .= $options['ext'];
    }
    if (isset($plugin)) {
        $path = Inflector::underscore($plugin) . '/' . $path;
    }

    $path = $this->_encodeUrl($this->assetTimestamp($this->webroot($path)));
    if ($legitCDN) {
        $path = rtrim($cdnBaseUrl, '/') . '/' . ltrim($path, '/');
    }
    return $path;
}
```

This is the sample code for the assetUrl

props to @lorenzo at https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/2149 for this solution

P.S.: I have rewritten the above as a Plugin.

So you can simply have the AppHelper extend this CDNAppHelper instead.

https://github.com/simkimsia/UtilityHelpers

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for simplest stuff just update few parameters in end of your core.php file

```
Configure::write('App.imageBaseUrl', 'http://cdn.yourdomain.com/img/');    
Configure::write('App.cssBaseUrl', 'http://cdn.yourdomain.com/css/');    
Configure::write('App.jsBaseUrl', 'http://cdn.yourdomain.com/js/');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $this->Html->css('alpha_landing/styles', array(
'fullBase' => true,
'pathPrefix'=>$cdnBaseUrl.'css/'));
```

Try this one